# Azure AD Protected Web API calls failed with Consent error

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-active-directory

I have an application(WebApp) which calls external API(WebApi1) and WebApi1 calls Another external Api WebApi2.

I have given application permission to WebApi1 from WebApp
Similarly application permission to WebApi2 from WebApi1

I got consent page for WebApi1 and accepted it, it works fine for WebApi1. But when I tried to call WebApi2 with on behalf of user from WebApi1, it throws consent page error.

> AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the
>   application with ID

Comment: To confirm, do you integrate the AAD in your web api applications in your own code logic? Or config in portal? And have you tried config the `knownClientApplications` in AAD application's manifest as mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent

Comment: I have tried with KnownClientApplications, but still issue with code blog - Thanks Gary, I have tried with KnownClientApplications in manifest. When I tried the below code blog it throwing that exception - AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(webApi2ResourceId, clientCred, userAssertion).Result;

Comment: Also all azure applications are single tenant

Comment: Have you fixed this issue?

Comment: Not fixed, the same code worked in one machine, but in my machine and some others. not sure, what went wrong!

Comment: Is it helpful to append the `prompt=consent` to the login request for the web app?

Answer (score 0):

If you register the app from [Azure portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), there is no need to config the `knownClientApplications` since it already give the consent when we register the app.

And if you register from other portal, after you config the `KnownClientApplications` you need to grant the permission again to use the parameter `prompt=consent`. In this time, the web app will also require you to give the consent to the web api2. After you grant the consent, the issue should be fixed.